# Generating ssh Keys for different user Accounts for an application inside a single box

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, ssh-keys

What would be the Procedure to generate ssh-keys for multiple user accounts (like root/admin/oracle accounts) assuming all the user accounts reside inside the same box.

How can the keys be differentiated based on the user accounts? Considering I am generating these Keys from my desktop using ssh-keygen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read **man ssh-keygen** attentively, it contains answer to your question

Use `ssh-keygen -n`